# Is there a way to make a dictionary global in TCL 8.4

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I build a dictionary in tcl 8.4 inside a procedure. How do I use the constructed dictionary in another procedure. I have added a sample code of how I construct a dictionary in tcl 8.4. I know tcl 8.5 has in built in 'dict' option, but I have to use tcl 8.4.

```
proc a {} {
    set test(key1) "value1"
    set test(key2) "value2"
    lappend keylist "key1"
    lappend keylist "key2"
    foreach key $keylist {
            puts "value of $key is $test($key)"
    }
}
```

So the procedure mentioned above builds a dictionary. But since tcl 8.4 interpreter interprets every line "$test($key)" as a separate variable how can I make it global so that I can use it in another procedure.

Comment: You really ought to upgrade to 8.5 or 8.6 if you can; 8.4 is no longer supported even for security or build fixes…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`global`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/global.htm) command to make a variable or array a global one.

For instance:

```
proc a {} {
    global test
    set test(key1) "value1"
    set test(key2) "value2"
    lappend keylist "key1"
    lappend keylist "key2"
    foreach key $keylist {
        puts "value of $key is $test($key)"
    }
}

a

# Outputs
# value of key1 is value1
# value of key2 is value2

# Now use them in another proc...
prob b {} {
    global test
    puts $test(key1)
    puts $test(key2)
}

b

# Outputs
# value1
# value2
```

Comment: This is great. I thought for me to manipulate a global variable, I should first declare it outside the procedure.(More like in C) That always ended in error.

Comment: You can do things outside the procedure first if you want, but you still have to explicitly bring the things outside into scope. (Or you could use fully-qualified variable names; they come with a bit of a performance penalty for multiple uses though.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to return the dictionary, you could pass it in to another proc as a parameter.  (Would have preferred to put this in the comment section, but I do not have the required rep)

Comment: I don think its possible since by dictionary we mean a collection of key value pairs. But since tcl 8.4 doesnt look at the structure as dictionary, it preserves the 'value' part when returned but not the 'key' part (since its mere variable). More over by doing this we can return only one value and the collection is lost.